# Can I add something like an anti-dependency to a debian package?

Tags: debian, deb

I have two packages of the same library but with very different APIs. Each of that library version shall have its own package, e.g. lib1.deb and lib2.deb.
I dont want to rename all the libs and headers in order to make them coexistable but then some libs/headers will will have the same path /overwrite each other. In a "control" file, when f.i. generating a package with debuild, can I somehow specify a package that must not be installed at the same time my other package is installed?
It would be nice that if when trying to install package2, that apt automatically wants to remove package1. I think I already saw something like that when installing packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should still consider making those packages co-installable (just imagine, you need to install a graphics program and `apt` wants to remove your entire networking stack, just because some "clever" package maintainer decided that it was much easier to put in a `Conflicts` than to resolve the issue).

Usually it is not that hard:

- put all header files into library-specific subdirectories, e.g. `/usr/include/lib1/` resp. `/usr/include/lib2/` (any well-written library should provide a pkg-config file which needs to be updated anyhow).
- normally, the library files are few, mostly 3 (`libfoo.so.x.y`, `libfoo.so.x`, `libfoo.x`). renaming them individually should be easy enough. (and again, update your pkg-config file to reflect the name-change).

Finally: "*two packages of the same library but with very different APIs*" sounds like a **very bad** idea in general. why are they the *same* library if they don't have the *same* API/ABI?

Oh, and if this is only about (incompatible) *versions*, this is usually handled as:

- `libfoo3` is the package of `libfoo` with ABI-version 3 e.g. it provides `/usr/lib/libfoo.so.3.14` and `/usr/lib/libfoo.so.3` which is a symlink to the former
- `libfoo7` is the package of `libfoo` with ABI-version 7 e.g. it provides `/usr/lib/libfoo.so.7.42` and `/usr/lib/libfoo.so.7` which is a symlink to the former)

  - `libfoo-dev` is the development package, which provides the headers and a symlink `/usr/lib/libfoo.so` to the *correct* ABI soname (`/usr/lib/libfoo.so.3` resp `/usr/lib/libfoo.so.7`). this package has a `Depends` on the correct `libfooX`, using an exact version specifier.

You can only have a single version of `libfoo-dev` installed (since `apt` prohibits a single package be installed multiple time).
However, you can have both `libfoo3` and `libfoo7` installed in parallel (which is important for the applications using it).

Comment: would it be ok to have libfoo3-dev packages then too or is that bad practice? And the include directory would be /usr/include/foo3 instead of /usr/include/libfoo3 wrt convention, right?

Comment: if you want the developer packages (`lib*-dev`) of both versions to be co-installable you can of course `libfoo3-dev`. there's a number of packages that do this (`apt-cache search lib*[0-9]-dev`), but it it not a very common pattern. as for the include-paths, both conventions exist (just check your `/usr/include` path - e.g. here i find both `/usr/include/harfbuzz` and `/usr/include/libsoup-2.4/`). if the version-number suffix is specific to your package, i *think* that it is common to use a dash: `/usr/include/foo-3`

Answer (score 0):

Hm, found a post on stackexchange covering that https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/393243

there are "Breaks" and "Conflicts" keywords seemingly https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/#conflicting-binary-packages-conflicts